# Python pandas: calculate rolling mean based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that shows the closing value for a bunch of stocks for the last 10 days. It has a datetime index & stocks can be identified by their name/code. Can you help me figure out how to calculate the 4 day moving average for each separate stock in the dataframe?

I've tried to use the pd.DataFrame.rolling().mean() method but it just gives the rolling mean for the whole dataset. Not sure where to go next...

`sampleData = hundredDayData['2019-03-11':'2019-03-20']
sampleData['Close: 4 day mean'] = sampleData['Close'].rolling(window=4).mean()
sampleData.head(24)`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['a']*10+['b']*10, 'Close': [1]*20})
df.groupby('code')['Close'].rolling(window=4).mean().reset_index()
```

- Group by `code` and calculate rolling mean with in the group

Note: If your `code's` are all jumbled (as shown below), then you should be using

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['a']*10+['b']*10+['a']*10, 'Close': [1]*30})
rolling = df.groupby('code')['Close'].rolling(window=4).mean().reset_index().set_index('level_1').rename(
    columns={'Close':'rolling'})[['rolling']]
df.merge(rolling, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Calculate rolling mean at group level but use the index to merge it back into the main dataframe as a new column.